# Is there a way to convert a string into bits in MicroPython?

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

While using MicroPython, I recently copied my "toBits()" function from python. My code is this:

```
def tobits(s):
    bits = ""
    for c in s:
        bits2 = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in c)
        bits = bits + bits2
   return bits
```

However, When using this function, I got the error: "NameError: name 'format' isn't defined"

I'm assuming MicroPython doesn't have "format" in it. Is there a different way to convert a string to bits in MicroPython?

Comment: Does `bin(i)` work?

Comment: `format()` is not a python function. Perhaps this function is in the code that you copied the `tobits()` function from, so you should copy it, too.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) _is_ a built-in function.

Comment: @Brian I see now. I was thinking of `str.format()` and didn't realize there is a global `format()`.

Comment: This function works in Python, it just doesn't work in MicroPython, because MicroPython doesn't have the format function. I am wondering if there is an alternative in MicroPython?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured this out, I ended up replacing the bits2 line with:

```
bits2 = ''.join('{:08b}'.format(ord(i)) for i in c)
```

Comment: So the `format` member function for strings exists but the free standing function doesn't? That makes no sense.

Comment: I agree, I found someone with a similar problem here: https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8561 Not sure why the free standing function isn't in micropython

Answer (score 0):

I know this works in regular Python, not sure about MicroPython.

```
bits = ''.join(bin(i)[2:].rjust(8,'0') for i in c)
```

Comment: I tried "bits2 = ''.join(bin(i)[2:].rjust(8,'0') for i in map(int, c))" in MicroPython, and got the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rjust'", it looks like micro python doesn't support that function, which I found here:
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/genrst/builtin_types.html?highlight=rjust
However, they say that I should be able to use the format() function as a workaround, even though it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I just figured out a work around, thanks for your help!